# show textbox when checkbox "OTHERS" is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show textbox when OTHERS checkbox is checked.

I have tried below script. But it's not working. It is good when use combobox.

```
 $('input[name=ctrl_CheckedList_qflht]').on('click',(function () {

 if ($(this).val() === "OTHERS") {

    console.dir(element);

  if (element.checked) {

  $('input[name=" ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"]').show();

   }
     else {

    $('input[name=" ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"]').hide();

    }

 }

  } ) );
```

Comment: try on change `$('input[name=ctrl_CheckedList_qflht]').on('change',`

Comment: .show and .hide function not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="ctrl_CheckedList_qflht" value="OTHERS" checked="true">
    <input id="" name="ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"  class="" >
    <script>
        $('input[name="ctrl_CheckedList_qflht"]').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "OTHERS") {
                console.log(this.checked);
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('input[name="ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"]').show();
                }else {
                    $('input[name="ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"]').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove your space " ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg" -> "ctrl_Textbox_pwwxg"

try this:

```
$('input[name="ctrl_CheckedList_qflht"]').change(function() {
    // this represents the checkbox that was checked
    // do something with it
});
```

Comment: I used change instead of click but still same. Nothing happen

Comment: "element.checked" change to "this.checked"